# Reuse schemas in Joi

Tags: node.js, joi, hapi.js

When using Joi for validation I often have two schemas that are very similar. One for creating a resource and one for changing a resource. The schema to change a resource often ist the same with all attributes being optional. Is there a way in Joi to take a schema and make all values optional?

Answer (score 5):

As the first answer said, you can use `.keys()`, but let me show you with a example:

```js
const Joi = require('joi')

const username = Joi.string()

const updateUser = Joi.object().keys({
  username
})

const createUser = Joi.object().keys({
  username: username.required()
})

updateUser.validate({}) //  OK { value: {} }

createUser.validate({}) //  ERROR { value: {}, error: Error: '"username" is required' }
```

I have learned this reading the book "Getting Started with hapi.js", chapter six.

I hope it is useful to you.

- [Documentation about `keys()`](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.4.0#objectkeysschema)
- [Book "Getting Started with hapi.js"](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/getting-started-with/9781785888182/)

Answer (score 1):

You can extend joi schemas using `.keys`

https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.3.0#objectkeysschema

Answer (score 1):

You can [fork](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.7.0#anyforkpaths-adjuster) a schema and include an adjuster function to modify the schema. It's an easy way to make all or some fields of a joi schema optional or required. A good advantage of `fork` is that it doesn't modify the original schema. Here's an example:

```
const UserSchema = {
  firstName: joi.string().required(),
  lastName: joi.string().required(),
  username: joi.string().required(),
};

// To create another schema for updating these fields where each key is optional:
const UpdateUserSchema = joi.object(UserSchema).fork(Object.keys(UserSchema), schema => schema.optional());

// To make some keys optional, you can pass an array with those keys to fork
const PartialUpdate = joi.object(UserSchema).fork(['username'], schema => schema.optional();
```